# When I enable @EnableResourceServer AND @EnableAuthorizationServer I get problems with the login page

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth

I am working on combined authentication and resource server.

I tested and got the authentication working with a login page triggered by the redirect, token creation using authorization code etc all fine.

However when I turn on the resource server the redirct login page stops working with different security settings related problems.
I think it has to do with that both `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` AND the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has a `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method to override.
I tried using only one of them and even tried letting them both set the same settings etc but cannot get it to work properly.

For instance one of the problems I get is missing csrf in the model:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.parameterName"
>   (login:45)

What is the recommended way of doing this?

The purpose of this server is to:
- Act as an OAuth authentication server, mainly with authorization code flow which will show a login followed by an approval page to the user
- Also host the REST API which the OAuth client will connect to using the access token to access resources for the logged in user

The security config looks like this:

```
 http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/logout.do").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/myservice/api/**").authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
        .usernameParameter("name")
        .loginPage("/login")
    .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.do"));
```

And the login page is a simple thymeleaf login page.

Comment: Do you have CSRF enabled ?

Comment: Well before  @EnableResourceServer  (and only @EnableAuthorizationServer) it is automatically turned on by default.

However now it seems to get turned off, probably by the defaults in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

To my knowledge it is generall turned on in Spring security and you have explicitly turn it off? (csrrf().disable() etc) 

I guess the problem is that CSRF has to be ON for all the authorization calls but turned OFF for the resources...

Comment: I tried adding @Order(2) for the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to make it have priority and then the login works again.
However then the token authentication for accessing the REST API (ie the resources) does not work and just behaves like it is not authenticated (redirecting to the login).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

adding @Order(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter solve my problem.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems we solved this now.

We the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter we had to set:
@Order(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) to make things work properly.